# PyGTK-2.24.0 Installation cannot find NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, makefile, pygtk, configure

I am trying to build the PyGTK source from version 2.24.0 with a local (prefix=$HOME/.local) installation of python 3.5.2. Running the configure script produces:

```
$: ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local
....
configure: WARNING: Could not find a valid numpy installation, disabling.
....
The following modules will be built:

atk
pango
pangocairo
gtk with 2.18 API
gtk.glade
gtk.unixprint

Numpy support: no
```

Looking in `config.log`:

```
....
configure:12393: checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 version
configure:12400: result: 3.5
configure:12412: checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 platform
configure:12419: result: linux
configure:12426: checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 script directory
configure:12455: result: ${prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages
configure:12464: checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 extension module directory
configure:12493: result: ${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages
....
 ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=/home/me/.local/lib/pkgconfig:/home/me/.local/bin/libwx/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
....
ac_cv_env_PYGOBJECT_LIBS_value=-L/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi
....
am_cv_python_platform=linux
am_cv_python_pyexecdir='${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
am_cv_python_pythondir='${prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
am_cv_python_version=3.5
....
PYTHON='/home/me/.local/bin/python3.5'
PYTHON_EXEC_PREFIX='${exec_prefix}'
PYTHON_INCLUDES='-I/home/me/.local/include/python3.5m -I/home/csmall02/.local/include/python3.5m'
PYTHON_PLATFORM='linux'
PYTHON_PREFIX='${prefix}'
PYTHON_VERSION='3.5'
....
pyexecdir='${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
pythondir='${prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
```

Why can't this configure find the NumPy packages? My `lib/python3.5` directory looks like:

```
.local
`--lib
   `--python3.5
      `--site-packages
         |-- numpy
         |   |-- compat         |-- ma
         |   |-- core           |-- matrixlib
         |   |-- distutils      |-- polynomial
         |   |-- doc            |-- __pycache__
         |   |-- f2py           |-- random
         |   |-- fft            |-- testing
         |   |-- lib            `-- tests
         |   `-- linalg
         |-- numpy-1.11.1.dist-info
         `-- numpy-1.11.1-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg
             |-- EGG-INFO
             `-- numpy
                 |-- compat              |-- ma
                 |-- core                |-- matrixlib
                 |-- distutils           |-- polynomial
                 |-- doc                 |-- __pycache__
                 |-- f2py                |-- random
                 |-- fft                 |-- testing
                 |-- lib                 `-- tests
                 `-- linalg
```

The reason for the two numpy directories is I installed one using `pip install numpy` and the other I installed from source in the course of trying to fix this problem.

Also, I have no problem using `import numpy` and such in interactive python, so I *know* it's "there".

Does anyone know how to pass the location of NumPy directly?
Any other advice would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably it's not using Python 3 in `./configure` file. Check its version using `PYTHON --version`.

Comment: @Mahdi Thanks for responding. I think it's finding my local installation correctly. I have the environment variable `$PYTHON=/home/me/.local/bin/python3.5` and configure returns: `checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 version... 3.5
checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 platform... linux
checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages
checking for /home/me/.local/bin/python3.5 extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have some mix-up.
Here is what I did :

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3 
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy 
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
sudo apt-get install python3-pyfits
```

One can also use `pip3` to install those libs, but using pip will install them for python 2.7...

Also, pygtk for python3 seems not to be available, read [the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97023/why-cant-i-import-pygtk-with-python-3-2-from-pydev)

Hope this clears things up so that you can solve it.